# Cron default mail transmission

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I just setup a cronjob in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` which is running fine. But when the cron starts I always get an email with following contents:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

 0     0    0     0    0    28      0  11340 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11340
 0 75 0 75 0 28 8480   3165 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7833
{"status": "ok", "jobs": {"mdspider": "e8ce7498dc5e11e0b387b3171f8e7a38"}}
```

Where can I disable that and enable email transmission only if the cronjob fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron will send you any output from your job; it is your task to write a job which doesn't spew spurious output. This looks vaguely like a Python script driving curl or maybe rsync; add a `-q` option to the script, or redirect its output to `/dev/null`. But take care to only ditch harmless messages! People tend to throw away error messages, and then wonder why their job fails "silently". A good practice is to log output to a file, and rotate the log file periodically.